# Why can Pauli channels be simulated efficiently?

Tags: quantum-algorithms

Why can Pauli channels be simulated efficiently on a classical computer (for the purpose of noise simulation)?

Could you please help me get an intuitive understanding and also point me to some references?

Thanks!

Comment: Another important follow up question is you might want to ask here is “how representative are Pauli errors of the complete set of errors that can occur on a quantum computer?”

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I went ahead and asked exactly the same question. Not sure if there is a way to give credit to the asker (as rightly framed questions are more valuable than answers). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pauli errors can be simulated efficiently *in stabilizer circuits* because the error propagation rules are so simple. Although stabilizer gates transform Pauli errors into other errors, they don't turn them into *different more complicated kinds* of errors. For example, a Hadamard gate will turn an X error into a Z error, which is still a Pauli error. Because of this simple-error-transformation property, you can summarize all currently-relevant errors by tagging each qubit with whether it currently has no error, X error, Y error, or Z error. When you measure a qubit tagged X or Y, the measurement result is flipped. This is very little information to track, and it can be updated cheaply.

The second key thing is that stabilizer circuits (with no complex feedback or branching) have the property that the hard part is collecting one good reference sample. Then you can derive more samples by injecting noise into the reference sample. For example, on thousand qubit circuits with millions of measurements, Stim can take a few seconds to produce its reference sample. But then it starts spitting out thousands of circuit samples per second. What it's doing is pretending noiseless runs always produce the reference sample, except it's perturbed by the noise in the circuit. A key thing here is that the distinction between different choices of reference sample is removed by adding a 50/50 Z error after every reset and measurement. The set of noiseless samples forms a group and you sample uniformly from that group via these 50/50 Z errors.

Comment: Thank you so much Craig. This is very clear. Could you also give me an example of a non-Pauli error which becomes very expensive to track when propagated? This will help me understand the complete story.

Comment: @Sam try tracking a T error